# Technical term for a constraint on an object in imperative programming

Tags: oop, imperative-programming

I know there's a technical term for this and for the life of me I can't remember it:

When designing a class (or some kind of thing with a functions and data), each call to the object's methods should leave the object's data in a consistent state.  "Consistent" means in accord with a series of (hopefully documented, usually not programmed in) constraints called [X]s.

Comment: I believe this should be asked on programmers.se

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're getting at "invariants".

Preconditions are things that must be true prior to a method execution.  Invariants are things that are always *publicly* true, and post-conditions are things true following method execution.

Comment: Yep, "invariants" was the word I was looking for.  Thanks!